# Error message with lmer: "number of levels of each grouping factor is > number of observations (problems: Participant)"

Tags: r, error-handling, lme4

I am not so familiar with R. I hope my question is not too stupid, but I got this error message

> Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: Participant)".

I have no idea what to do... Here are my codes.

Load the necessary packages

```r
library(lme4)
library(dplyr)
```

```r
# Convert categorical variables to factors
data <- data %>%
  mutate(across(c(AoA_L1, AoA_L2, AoA_L3, AoA_L4, AoA_L4, AoA_L5, AoA_L6, AoA_L7, AoA_L8, MOI_L1, MOI_L2, MOI_L3, MOI_L4, MOI_L5, MOI_L6, MOI_L7, MOI_L8, Learning_L1, Learning_L2, Learning_L3, Learning_L4, Learning_L5, Learning_L6, Learning_L7, Learning_L8), as.factor))

# Add a column for the number of known languages
data$known_languages <- rowSums(!is.na(data[, c("L1", "L2", 
    "L3", "L4", "L5", "L6", "L7", "L8")]))

# Step 3: Replace missing values with zeros (if desired)
data[is.na(data)] <- 0

# Convert "Participant" to a character vector and then back to a factor variable
data$Participant <- factor(as.character(data$Participant))

# Perform the mixed-effects linear regression analysis with a varying slope
model <- lmer(L1_L2Tra + L1_L3Tra + L1_L4Tra + 
  L1_L5Tra + L1_L6Tra + L1_L7Tra + L1_L8Tra + L2_L3Tra + L2_L4Tra + 
  L2_L5Tra + L2_L6Tra + L2_L7Tra + L2_L8Tra + L3_L4Tra + L3_L5Tra + 
  L3_L6Tra + L3_L7Tra + L3_L8Tra + L4_L5Tra + L4_L6Tra + L4_L7Tra + 
  L4_L8Tra + L5_L6Tra + L5_L7Tra + L5_L8Tra + L6_L7Tra + L6_L8Tra + 
  L7_L8Tra ~ Lv_L1 + Lv_L2 + Lv_L3 + Lv_L4 + Lv_L5 + Lv_L6 + Lv_L7 + 
  Lv_L8 + Recency_L1 + Recency_L2 + Recency_L3 + Recency_L4 +
  Recency_L5 + Recency_L6 + Recency_L7 + Recency_L8 + 
  AoA_L1 + AoA_L2 + AoA_L3 + AoA_L4 + AoA_L4 + AoA_L5 + AoA_L6 + 
  AoA_L7 + AoA_L8 + MOI_L1 + MOI_L2 + MOI_L3 + MOI_L4 + MOI_L5 +
  MOI_L6 + MOI_L7 + MOI_L8 + Learning_L1 + Learning_L2 + Learning_L3 +
  Learning_L4 + Learning_L5 + Learning_L6 + Learning_L7 + Learning_L8 + 
  (1 + known_languages | Participant), data = data)

# View the summary of the model
summary(model)
```

Comment: I guess the each Participant has his own row - never multiple rows?

Comment: How many participants do you have, and how many observations? What is `table(table(data$Participant))` ? Is the number of languages known for each participant fixed over the course of your observations?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Every participant has their own row. I have 38 participants. Some of them speak 4 languages, some of them speak 5 languages, the max. is 8 languages